# How to check whether or not the user is n admin instead of a normal user for all my admin functions?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First off, heres my code:

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}

 function logout()
{
$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
session_destroy();
redirect('home', 'refresh');
}    

public function index()
  {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
 {
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
if  ($session_data['id'] != 1){
    $this->load->view('head');
    echo "Sorry, you have to be an administrator to access this page";
    $this->load->view('footer');

} else {
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
$this->load->view('head');
$this->load->model('admin_model');
$data['users'] = $this->admin_model->show_data(); 
$data['bikes'] = $this->admin_model->show_bikes();
$this->load->view('admin', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');

}
} else
{
 redirect('login', 'refresh');
}

}
```

The dilemma I'm in is, yes this will stop all normal users accessing the admin/index page. However they still will be able to access admin/create, admin/update and so on unless i put an if statement on all the functions which will take some time. Is there a quicker way (possibly something i could put in the construct) that will apply the check to all the admin pages? Thanks

Comment: Is this function part of a Controller class? Are you using a particular framework here?

Comment: Im using Code igniter. And yes its part of the class. The class is called Admin. the functions are called create, update, index for example updating a users data therefore shouldn't be accessible by a normal user

Comment: i will update the question so you can see its part of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move your admin-check code to the constructor:

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
    if  ($session_data['id'] != 1){
        $this->load->view('head');
        echo "Sorry, you have to be an administrator to access this page";
        $this->load->view('footer');
        exit; // or return? sorry, not too familiar w/ CodeIgniter
    }

    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}

...

public function index()
{    
    ...
}
```